# how to use this properly? my application stopped when i adding this code

Tags: java, android

```
public int getCurrentCursorLine(`EditText editText`) {    
    int selectionStart = Selection.getSelectionStart(editText.getText());
    Layout layout = editText.getLayout();
    if (!(selectionStart == -1)) 
    {
        return layout.getLineForOffset(selectionStart);
    }
    return -1; }
```

Comment: Please remove `' '` in method. User `getCurrentCursorLine(EditText editText){}`.

Comment: sir shailesh actually it's not the problem, this " ' ' " was added because im new on posting in stackoverflow,

what i want to know is how to add this line of code?


i did this

int sample= getCurrentCursorLine(sampleEditText);

but it's not working

Comment: Please share some more code. Means where you can add this code and please post your error log code.

Comment: `  int sample=getCurrentCursorLine(txtInput);
  Log.e("tag",sample + "");
  
  
 }

 public int getCurrentCursorLine(MultiAutoCompleteTextView txtInput)
 {    
     int selectionStart = Selection.getSelectionStart(txtInput.getText());
     Layout layout = txtInput.getLayout();

     if (!(selectionStart == -1)) {
         return layout.getLineForOffset(selectionStart);
     }

     return -1;
 }`

Comment: 03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879): Process: com.example.try5, PID: 12879
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.try5/com.example.try5.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2319)

Comment: 03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

Comment: 03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

Comment: 03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: 03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at com.example.try5.MainActivity.getCurrentCursorLine(MainActivity.java:170)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at com.example.try5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:158)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5296)

Comment: 03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
03-18 14:58:58.300: E/AndroidRuntime(12879):  ... 11 more

Comment: im sorry , if i made this unprofessional

Comment: @AngGulo Post your stacktrace in Question, not in comments.

Comment: You have issue, in line#158 of your MainActivity.java

Comment: @Rasi ,that error is this  int sample=getCurrentCursorLine(txtInput);
  Log.e("tag",sample + "");

Comment: Are you sure txtInput is not null, you used correct id of EditText ?

Comment: @Rasi oh God thank you, you are corrent my problem is my edittext is null hahaha so i just add it on text change listener and it works thank you so much God bless

Answer (score 1):

As from your stacktrace it is clear you are getting some value null on which you trying to do some operation.

Make sure -
1. You have correct layout file in `setContentView`.

2. Correct id is used for `EditText`.